# In "msg.sender.call.value(msg.value)", where is msg.value taken from?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Given the following example:

```
function x(address receiver) public {
    receiver.call.value(msg.value)();
}
```

Am I correct that `receiver` can be any address but `msg.value` cannot be controlled via argument? Will `msg.value` always be zero or will it be taken from `msg.sender`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `msg.value` is always the amount of Ethers sent with the (internal) transaction - if contract `A` calls contract `B` it may pass along less Ethers than `msg.value` and then `msg.value` in `B` is the new amount. So, yes, the whole amount will be taken from `msg.sender` (or, more specifically, from `tx.origin` - the EOA who initially started the transaction).

However in your example the value is always 0 as your function can't accept Ethers - it's not marked as `payable`. But if you make it accept Ethers then whatever value I send with the transaction gets passed to the `receiver`; your function simply relays the value forward.

I actually had to test around to see how `msg.value` behaves when another contract is called with less Ethers due to a comment from @eth. As I said, the amount of `msg.value` *can* go lower than the original amount. Here's the code I used. You can test it by sending some Ethers to contract `A`:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract A {
    function a() payable external {
        B bb = new B();
        bb.b.value(msg.value / 2)();
    }
}

contract B {
    event showb(uint);
    function b() payable external {
        emit showb(msg.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The first sentence might be inaccurate and may need testing. For example, if a contract invoked `x()` and only sent it half the `msg.value` of the transaction, then `receiver` would only get this amount, not the whole amount that was sent in the transaction. I think is an opportunity to verify/explain this case, if you would like to.

Comment: Ahh, an excellent observation. Thanks, tested anew and edited answer.